# How to transformation in SSIS when I have multiple flat file using Merge Join?

Tags: sql-server, join, merge, ssis, etl

I have multiple flat files based on which I need to transformation. I have at least 5 or 6 flat files which I have to use Merge Join to get final outcomes but after reading other articles I came to know I can only use two flat file source to use Merge join. Does anyone has experience or know how to use merge join when you have multiple flat file source( 5 or 6)?

Comment: Sounds awful. I would dump all the raw data into tables and then query them there.

Comment: Can you union the files together or do they each have different schema?

Comment: @JacobH, I dont have any option of loading these data into database table. It should be all from flat  file to flat file . My source and destination both are flat file.

Comment: @BaconBits, I can not do union because only one column from each mapping file match to main file so merge join is only one option for me so far I know .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple merge join transformation instead of linking all sources into one merge join transformation, you can refer to the following link for an example:

- [merging two or more tables in SSIS](https://krazycoder.wordpress.com/2010/06/24/merging-two-or-more-tables-in-ssis/)

Comment: I will try this logic soon and update this thread if this solve my problem .